# Is Star Trek Vanguard part Prime timeline, part Kelvin timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-eu

A few years ago, I read somewhere that *[Star Trek: Vanguard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Vanguard)* started as depicting events of the Prime Timeline, but was transferred into the Kelvin Timeline. I can't find the source anymore, but wonder if this statement is actually correct.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure it isn't

Comment: @Valorum Thank you. I was thinking about picking it up but lack any interest in the Kelvin timeline.

Comment: I've got it but not read it. I can't find anything online about it being in the Kelvin timeline and a quick glance through has zero mentions of Nero, the Narada or Kelvin